# Weird eclipse juno plugin interactions

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ubuntu

I recently upgraded to eclipse Juno(on ubuntu 12.04) and the first thing i installed was the Android SDK and ADT. This gave me access to the wizards to create android projects, classes, etc. pretty standard stuff..

Problems start when i try to install other plugins.eg.repast symphony. aptana, code recommender from eclipse and Google's window builder pro. Specifically, **neither can be installed without automatically uninstalling the other.** They each have their installation peculiarities, that i accept. But the point is only one seems to "want" to be installed at a time.

I found a workaround for this, though. This involved uninstalling all plugins, then reinstalling each as root. This worked fine. But this also means I have to run eclipse as root everytime. Being no pro at the linux file system i think it very unwise to continue as I have already messed up the permissions on eclipse related file systems.

Might any one have come across this problem or can anyone render some solutions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo nautilus to copy the plugins to the dropins folder and use file properties to set the group to users and enable read permission .

You then, should not then need to run eclipse as root.